# "Grid" menu is missing from SAGA on my QGIS 2.18 setup

Tags: qgis-processing, saga, contour, grids-graticules

I am just a learner and learning through internet tutorials. I tried to learn about SAGA tools specially for "Grid" options, but I am unable to see any menu icon of Grid on SAGA toolbar.

I am wondering if anything wrong happened, or if QGIS 2.18 doesn't provide anything for Grid/Contour processing from SAGA?

Comment: Try the `Raster` tools in the SAGA processing section.

Answer (score 2):

*[Copied]*

Try the `Raster` tools in the SAGA processing section. ---  **AndreJ** *(Dec 4'17)*

---

Naming convention:

- `Grid` tools in SAGA are called `Raster` tools in QGIS
- `Shapes` tools in SAGA are `Vector` tools in QGIS